# How can we get a list of failed specs in protractor?

Tags: protractor, slack-api, e2e-testing, slack

I am using Protractor for e2e testing, in the protractor config file in the `afterLaunch` function i am trying to get a list of all the failed specs so that I can send a slack message on the appropriate channel in slack, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

This is not about Protractor alone, but about the testing framework used under-the-hood. Assuming you are using `jasmine`, you need to make a [custom jasmine reporter](http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/custom_reporter.html) and get the `result.failedExpectations` from the `specDone` and `suiteDone` callbacks to get to the expectation failures and check the `spec.status` in the `specDone` callback to see if it failed or not.

For the sample reporters, please see:

- [`jasmine-spec-reporter`](https://github.com/bcaudan/jasmine-spec-reporter)
- [`jasmine-reporters`](https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters)

Comment: how can we retain a list of all the failed specs? apparently the config file is getting each time and hence it overwrites any global variable. is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: @jp310 could you please create a separate question providing what you have so far and the desired output, I think this way more people can help you and potentially benefit from having a question like that on SO. Thanks!

Comment: here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39232415/how-to-make-a-list-of-failed-specs-using-jasmine-custom-reporter-to-post-to-slack

Comment: I had this working till i updated to protractor 4.0.7 and now none of the custom jasmine reporters are working. Any idea what could have caused this?